# Force split action bar on Android for large screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there a way to force the action bar to be split on large screens?

I really like the way the UI looks with a split action bar. I can use uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" but that only does it for small screens. I want it to be that way for all screens.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html